# Managing a local/clone copy of a project with git

Tags: git, github

There are a couple of projects I am interested to work with and they are all in github, so I need a basic understanding. So far I manage to setup git and grab a copy of the project** using git clone, I get updates by calling git pull, but I need to know:

1- How can I reverse to a previous state of the project after a git pull?

2- Is it possible with my setup** to get the latest updates in a different place, test and them merge if I am happy with the changes? how?

3- Do you recommend to Fork the project, even if I wont be contributing to it?

That is it for the moment, many thanks!

** Please note that I am not Forking the project, so I don't have a Copy of the Repo remotely, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `git reset` or `git checkout` (with the right parameters) to go to a old state of the tree. `reset` changes what the current branch points to, while `checkout` leaves the branch and switches to another, or to a commit not on a branch.
2. Yes. Just have an own branch, into which to merge (or not merge).
3. Forking has a github specific meaning here - it means that under your name is another repository, which then helps tracking the upstream one - and github rememembers from which repository it came from, draws the right diagrams and so on. As long as you never commit anything different than upstream, there is not really a point, apart from showing that you follow this repository.

Comment: People 'forked' projects long before GitHub. Let me quote Version Control with Git (hope author - Jon Loeliger - won't mind): "In his work on the Linux kernel, Linus Torvalds eventually realized that forking is a problem only if the forks don’t eventually merge back together. Thus, he designed Git to look at forking totally differently: Git encourages forking. But Git also makes it easy for anyone to merge two forks whenever they want."

Comment: Yeah, this was worded badly ... not forking is a github specific thing, but making a difference between forking and cloning.

Comment: ŭlo Now I see OP stated that he won't be contributing back, so my comment isn't actually relevant, but nevertheless the idea about forking being a good thing is good :)

Comment: So best practice will be to create a branch, git pull to master and if I need to revert to the previous commit I can either change branch or reset, am I right?